# Why does my new if statement break my function?

Tags: javascript

I am new to javascript. I just made a very simple game where a knight jumps over a rock, however, the rock was an infinite animation. I am trying to add various rock speeds, but for some reason, my new code breaks my game. Here is my full code: https://codepen.io/flyingchicken22/pen/BadBLre
This is the code that I added (with snippets of my other code:
CSS:

```
#rock {
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    position: relative;
    top: 122px;
    left: 550px;
    background-image: url("http://pixelartmaker-data-78746291193.nyc3.digitaloceanspaces.com/image/da268f06e621b21.png");
    background-size: cover;
}

.rockAnimationFast {
    animation: rockAnimationFast 0.75s linear;
}

.rockAnimationMedium {
    animation: rockAnimationMedium 1s linear;
}

.rockAnimationSlow {
    animation: rockAnimationSlow 1.5s linear;
}

@keyframes rockAnimationFast {
    0%{left: 500px;}
    100%{left: -50px;}
}

@keyframes rockAnimationMedium {
    0%{left: 500px;}
    100%{left: -50px;}
}

@keyframes rockAnimationSlow {
    0%{left: 500px;}
    100%{left: -50px;}
}
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
function play() {
    let dead = false
    if (dead==false) {
        let falseVar = false
        while (falseVar == false) {
    
            console.log("working")
            function rockAnimationSlow() {
                document.getElementById("rock").classList.add('rockAnimationSlow')
                setTimeout(() => {
                    document.getElementById("rock").classList.remove('rockAnimationSlow')
                }, 1500);
            }
            
            function rockAnimationMedium() {
                let rock = document.getElementById("rock")
                rock.classList.add('rockAnimationMedium')
                setTimeout(() => {
                    rock.classList.remove('rockAnimationMedium')
                }, 1000);
            }
    
            function rockAnimationFast() {
                let rock = document.getElementById("rock")
                rock.classList.add('rockAnimationFast')
                setTimeout(() => {
                    rock.classList.remove('rockAnimationFast')
                    
                }, 750);
            }
            let randRockSpeed = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)
            
            
            if (randRockSpeed <= 3) {
                rockAnimationFast()
            }
    
            if (randRockSpeed <= 7 && randRockSpeed > 3) {
                rockAnimationMedium()
                
            }
    
            if (randRockSpeed <= 10 && randRockSpeed > 7) {
                rockAnimationSlow()
            }
    }
    }
}
```

Thank you so much!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

It is not the if statement that breaks the code, but rather your infinite while loop (which I assume you are using to animate your game). However, animations need to be handled differently, since infinite loop basically block the main thread indefinitely, causing the browser to crash. The way it is usually done is with [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame). Here's what it could look like in action in your case :

```js
let dead = false


function update() {
  if (dead == false) {
    let falseVar = false


    console.log("working")

    function rockAnimationSlow() {
      document.getElementById("rock").classList.add('rockAnimationSlow')
      setTimeout(() => {
        document.getElementById("rock").classList.remove('rockAnimationSlow')
      }, 1500);
    }

    function rockAnimationMedium() {
      let rock = document.getElementById("rock")
      rock.classList.add('rockAnimationMedium')
      setTimeout(() => {
        rock.classList.remove('rockAnimationMedium')
      }, 1000);
    }

    function rockAnimationFast() {
      let rock = document.getElementById("rock")
      rock.classList.add('rockAnimationFast')
      setTimeout(() => {
        rock.classList.remove('rockAnimationFast')

      }, 750);
    }
    let randRockSpeed = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)


    if (randRockSpeed <= 3) {
      rockAnimationFast()
    }

    if (randRockSpeed <= 7 && randRockSpeed > 3) {
      rockAnimationMedium()

    }

    if (randRockSpeed <= 10 && randRockSpeed > 7) {
      rockAnimationSlow()
    }

  }
}


function play() {
  dead = false
  update()
  //transfers jump animation to script

  function jump() {
    knight.classList.add('jump-animation')
    setTimeout(() => {
      knight.classList.remove('jump-animation')
    }, 500)
  }
  //When any key is pressed, run jump animation
  document.addEventListener('keypress', () => {
    if (!knight.classList.contains('jump-animation') && dead == false) {
      jump();
    }
  })
  //game loop


  var gameLoop = setInterval(() => {
    score.innerText++
  }, 50)
}
let score = document.getElementById('score')




var gameLoop1 = setInterval(() => {



  const knight = document.getElementById('knight')
  const rock = document.getElementById('rock')


  const knightTop = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(knight).getPropertyValue('top'))
  const rockLeft = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(rock).getPropertyValue('left'))


  if (rockLeft < 0) {
    rock.style.display = 'none'
  } else {
    rock.style.display = ''
  }

  if (rockLeft < 90 && rockLeft > 50 && knightTop > 79) {
    dead = true
  }

  const deathAnimation = document.getElementById("deathAnimation")
  const game = document.getElementById("game")
  if (dead == true) {
    clearInterval(gameLoop)
    clearInterval(gameLoop1)
    game.classList.add(deathAnimation)
    document.getElementById("reload").style.animationPlayState = "running"
    document.getElementById("game").style.animationPlayState = "running"
    document.getElementById("rock").style.animationPlayState = "paused"
    document.getElementById("gameOver").style.animationPlayState = "running"
  }

  let scoreNum = document.getElementById("score")

  if (scoreNum == 1000) {
    //ENTER NEXT STAGE
    console.log("1000")
  }
}, 50)

function reload() {
  location.reload()
}
```

```css
html {
  background-color: black;
}

#score {
  font-family: 'Press Start 2P', cursive;
  text-align: center;
  color: rgba(102, 255, 0, 0.993);
}

#game {
  width: 600px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  margin: auto;
  background-image: url("https://t3.ftcdn.net/jpg/01/73/79/26/360_F_173792623_516juhwjkCCZJ9OyesyH7hf7r9zsyH5u.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  animation: deathAnimation 2s;
  animation-play-state: paused;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes deathAnimation {
  0% {
    filter: none;
  }
  100% {
    filter: grayscale(100%);
  }
}

#knight {
  height: 100px;
  width: 75px;
  position: relative;
  top: 171px;
  left: 50px;
  background-image: url("https://images-wixmp-ed30a86b8c4ca887773594c2.wixmp.com/f/f57b5304-de59-49e3-b0f9-cc29a2458425/dcgy8i3-e6dac283-04a7-40e5-a333-cc645e172df7.png?token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJ1cm46YXBwOjdlMGQxODg5ODIyNjQzNzNhNWYwZDQxNWVhMGQyNmUwIiwiaXNzIjoidXJuOmFwcDo3ZTBkMTg4OTgyMjY0MzczYTVmMGQ0MTVlYTBkMjZlMCIsIm9iaiI6W1t7InBhdGgiOiJcL2ZcL2Y1N2I1MzA0LWRlNTktNDllMy1iMGY5LWNjMjlhMjQ1ODQyNVwvZGNneThpMy1lNmRhYzI4My0wNGE3LTQwZTUtYTMzMy1jYzY0NWUxNzJkZjcucG5nIn1dXSwiYXVkIjpbInVybjpzZXJ2aWNlOmZpbGUuZG93bmxvYWQiXX0.0LapCzRi5sQjkqzwB5lwWQT_XH1BM4rSMZt7jrflMLk");
  background-size: cover;
}

#h3 {
  font-family: 'Press Start 2P', cursive;
  color: rgba(102, 255, 0, 0.993);
  text-align: center;
}

#rock {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  position: relative;
  top: 122px;
  left: 550px;
  background-image: url("http://pixelartmaker-data-78746291193.nyc3.digitaloceanspaces.com/image/da268f06e621b21.png");
  background-size: cover;
}

.rockAnimationFast {
  animation: rockAnimationFast 0.75s linear;
}

.rockAnimationMedium {
  animation: rockAnimationMedium 1s linear;
}

.rockAnimationSlow {
  animation: rockAnimationSlow 1.5s linear;
}

@keyframes rockAnimationFast {
  0% {
    left: 500px;
  }
  100% {
    left: -50px;
  }
}

@keyframes rockAnimationMedium {
  0% {
    left: 500px;
  }
  100% {
    left: -50px;
  }
}

@keyframes rockAnimationSlow {
  0% {
    left: 500px;
  }
  100% {
    left: -50px;
  }
}

.jump-animation {
  animation: jump 0.5s;
}

@keyframes jump {
  0% {
    top: 171px;
  }
  50% {
    top: 70px;
  }
  75% {
    top: 70px;
  }
  100% {
    top: 171px;
  }
}

#gameName {
  font-family: 'Press Start 2P', cursive;
  text-align: center;
  color: rgba(102, 255, 0, 0.993);
  font-size: 300%;
}

#gameOver {
  font-family: 'Press Start 2P', cursive;
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
  animation: gameOver 2s infinite;
  animation-play-state: paused;
}

@keyframes gameOver {
  0% {
    color: black;
  }
  50% {
    color: rgba(102, 255, 0, 0.993);
  }
  100% {
    color: black
  }
}

#reload {
  background: url("https://static.thenounproject.com/png/191594-200.png");
  margin: 200;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-size: cover;
  animation: reload 5s, move 0.5s infinite;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-play-state: paused;
}

@keyframes reload {
  0% {
    filter: none
  }
  100% {
    filter: invert(100%)
  }
}

@keyframes move {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg)
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate(10deg)
  }
  90% {
    transform: rotate(0deg)
  }
  93% {
    transform: rotate(0deg)
  }
  95% {
    transform: rotate(0deg)
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(0deg)
  }
}

#play {
  margin-left: 1150px;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-image: url("https://art.pixilart.com/a9b70c683c2aed9.png");
  background-size: cover;
}

#companyName {
  width: 10px;
  height: 5px;
  color: #7bafd4;
  font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
  margin-right: 500px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Press+Start+2P&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="game">
    <div id="knight"></div>
    <div id="rock"></div>

  </div>

  <h1 id="score">0</h1>
  <h3 id="highScore"></h3>
  <h1 id="gameName">KNIGHT HOPPER</h1>
  <h1 id="gameOver">Game Over</h1>
  <div id="play" onclick="play()"></div>
  <div id="reload" onclick="reload()"></div>
  <div id="companyName">flyingchicken</div>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Although some mistakes are still present here and there in your code (for example the gameLoop variable needs to be handled differently), I believe you are on the right track for your awesome project.

If you still struggle with the other bugs, please let me know, I will gladly help you.

Comment: Thank you so much for answering my question. I can't seem to understand window.requestAnimationFrame() and I was wondering if you could explain how I can use it? I would like the rock to run on an infinite loop, but at the moment it just runs once and stops. Thank you!